# Paginated response with FastAPI and SqlAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

How to paginate in FastAPI like in Django REST Framework? Below simple FastAPI application that demonstrates some pseudocode. Actually the main question in SqlAlchemy and how not to execute statement in function but execute it out of function. I guess there will be different code with v1 and v2 versions of SqlAlchemy.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi_filter import FilterDepends
from fastapi_filter.contrib.sqlalchemy import Filter
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext import asyncio as sa_asyncio
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

engine = sa_asyncio.create_async_engine(...)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=sa_asyncio.AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    last_name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    username = sa.Column(sa.String)
    email = sa.Column(sa.String)


class UserFilter(Filter):
    username: str
    email: str

    class Constants(Filter.Constants):
        model = User
        ordering_field_name = "ordering"


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    session = SessionLocal()

    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        await session.close()


async def fetch_users(session, filtering=None, limit=None, offset=None):
    stmt = sa.select(User)

    if filtering:
        stmt = filtering.filter(stmt)
        stmt = filtering.sort(stmt)

    if limit:
        stmt = stmt.limit(limit)

    if offset:
        stmt = stmt.offset(offset)

    # how not to execute but return executable so I could call f.e. method stmt.all() out of this function
    # like in DRF?
    result = await session.query(stmt)

    return result.scalars()


def paginate(query):
    # pseudocode
    # here I'd like to actually execute statement
    return {
        'count': query.count(),
        'result': query.all()
    }


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/users')
async def get_users(
    filtering: UserFilter = FilterDepends(UserFilter), limit: int = 10, offset: int = 0, session=Depends(get_session)
):
    users = await fetch_users(session, filtering, limit, offset)
    return paginate(users)
```

Comment: It seems it impossible with SqlAlchemy v2